# $row[''] in prepared statements PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to change my mysqli code to use prepared statements.

For some reason I cant get the usual `$row['']` to work. I have googled for a while but I just don't get it. My code without prepared statements is like this:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users")) {
        echo "
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($row['status'] == "1") {
                echo '<tr class="active">';
            } elseif($row['status'] == "2") {
                echo '<tr class="success">';
            } elseif($row['status'] == "0") {
                echo '<tr class="danger">';
            } else {
                echo '<tr class="warning">';
            }
     etc...
```

This is what I have so far with prepared statements:

```
$grab_user = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
if($grab_user->execute()) {
    echo "
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

    while($grab_user->fetch()) {
        $row = $grab_user->fetch_row();

        if($row['status'] == "1") {
            echo '<tr class="active">';
        } elseif($row['status'] == "2") {
            echo '<tr class="success">';
        } elseif($row['status'] == "0") {
            echo '<tr class="danger">';
        } else {
            echo '<tr class="warning">';
        }
```

Obviously it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer your question, but for a static query like that, there's nothing wrong with just using `mysqli_query()`. There's not much benefit from using a prepared statement with a query like that because you aren't binding any parameters to it. Prepared statements are mostly useful in helping to prevent SQL injection and improving performance when you're executing the same statement repeatedly with different input.

Comment: I'm not trying to say that you shouldn't learn how to use prepared statements in general. You definitely should. It just won't be as useful for this specific case. Also, when you do get to cases where you need to bind parameters, I think PDO is much easier to work with than mysqli. If you're still early in making this transition to prepared statements, you might consider trying PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an **array offset starting from 0 (zero)**.

so it should be something like `$row[0]`. Find out the index of status and then use appropriate value.

---

If you need to access with column names, you need to use [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) then.

like this:

```
while($row=$grab_user->fetch_assoc()) {    
    if($row['status'] == "1") {
        echo '<tr class="active">';
    } elseif($row['status'] == "2") {
        echo '<tr class="success">';
    } elseif($row['status'] == "0") {
        echo '<tr class="danger">';
    } else {
        echo '<tr class="warning">';
    }
}
```

---

`fetch_row` - numeric array

`fetch_assoc` - associative array

Comment: Thanks. And thanks to @Don't Panic as I query() works better

Answer (score 1):

If you want an associative array, you should be using `fetch_assoc()`, not `fetch_row()`, which returns a numeric array.

Also, you shouldn't call both `fetch()` and `fetch_assoc()` in the loop. Each of them will read the next row, so `fetch_assoc()` will only get every other row of the results. So it should be:

```
while ($row = $grab_user->fetch_assoc()) {
    ...
}
```